# PHP Web Service JSON Encoding

Tags: php, android, json, retrofit

I am messing around and creating a web services in php/json.

```
<?php
    $answer = array('status'=>401, 'answer'=>'');


    if($numWeeks%2 == 0) {
        $answer['answer'] = 'trash';
        utf8_encode($answer['answer']);
        $answer['status'] = 200;
    }
    else {
        $answer['answer'] = 'trach/recycle';
        utf8_encode($answer['answer']);
        $answer['status'] = 200;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($answer);
?>
```

The output:

```
{"status":200,"answer":"trash"}
```

I am also trying to read this with an android app using RETROFIT (v1.9).

My object class is:

```
public class TrashResponse {

    public int status;
    public String answer;


}
```

But i get this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

From my research it has to do with my json object from my web service. I cannot pin point what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your TrashResponse class **status** is of String type but the value in json is of Integer type. Modify it and try again to see if it works.

Comment: it did not work :( i still get the same error... i changed status to int type and not working

Comment: do you think it has to do with the json encoding not being UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to solve this you can in server side code

```
<?php
    $answer = array('status'=> "401", 'answer'=>'');


    if($numWeeks%2 == 0) {
        $answer['answer'] = 'trash';
        utf8_encode($answer['answer']);
        $answer['status'] = "200";
    }
    else {
        $answer['answer'] = 'trach/recycle';
        utf8_encode($answer['answer']);
        $answer['status'] = "200";
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($answer);
?>
```

by changing  **status as string**

**OR**

You can change in android side

```
public class TrashResponse {

    public int status;
    public String answer;
}
```

Better to make changes in android side

Answer (score 0):

The server I was using has an older version of PHP. I switched to another server with an updated version and added the following code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($answer, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This returned a valid JSON object. Originally, the JSON was invalid because my app was seeing the json object as a string.